# Cannot update a component (`DrawerNavigator`) while rendering a different component (`Main2`)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

When I go from one page to another, this error pops up, the transition is carried out, but I would like to get rid of this error, here is an example of my code, please tell me how to fix this error?

```
function Root() {

  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"
    
    //drawerContentOptions={{}}
    //drawerContent={<Text></Text>}
    screenOptions={{
      drawerActiveTintColor: '#0069B3',
      itemStyle: { marginVertical: 5 },
    }}
    drawerContent={(props) => <LeftMenu {...props} />}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="New" component={New}  options={{ drawerLabel: '1',title: "1", headerStyle:{backgroundColor: '#0069B3', height: 75}, headerTintColor: '#fff', headerTitleStyle:{fontSize: 22, fontWeight: '600'}, headerTitleAlign: 'left'}}/>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Main}  options={{ drawerLabel: '2',title: "2", headerStyle:{backgroundColor: '#0069B3', height: 75}, headerTintColor: '#fff', headerTitleStyle:{fontSize: 22, fontWeight: '600'}, headerTitleAlign: 'left'}}/>
    </Drawer.Navigator>  

);
}
export const Navigator =() =>{
    const Stack = createStackNavigator();
    return(
      
    <Stack.Navigator  screenOptions={{}} initialRouteName="Authorization">
    <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={Root}options={{ headerShown: false }}/> 
    <Stack.Screen name="Root2" component={Root2}options={{ headerShown: false }}/> 
    <Stack.Screen name="Authorization" component={Authorization} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>

  </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on my pages there was a navigation.setOptions parameter and I put it in useEffect

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).